# //= require と requireの違いがわかりません

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

jsファイルで、

```
//= require some.js
```

のようにjsファイルをrequireしているのを見つけたのですが、

```
var a = require('some.js')
```

の違いがわかりません。

`//= require` でググっても記事が出てこないので困っています。

Comment: 参考: [How to comment out rails 3.1 asset require statement - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6075353)

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントアウトの方は Rails のアセットパイプラインの記法ですね。

設定次第ですがデフォルトだと

本番環境で１ファイルに結合してくれる
本番環境で難読化してくれる
他のファイルで同じものを require しても重複しない

と言った違いがあります

Comment: minifyはあくまでもファイルサイズの削減が主目的で結果として多少読みにくくはなりますが難読化とは少し異なるかと。

Comment: railsでのアセットパイプラインの記法なのですね。馴染みがなかったのはそのせいだったのですね。その情報がわかっただけでも助かりました。